# How to identify what is causing a throttling exception in AWS lambda and how to handle the same

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, throttling

I have a node.js lambda that subscribes to a SQS queue and makes a REST API call to a microservice for every message from SQS.

Now as the lambda is executing I get the following exception

```
{
  "message": "Rate exceeded",
  "code": "ThrottlingException",
  "time": "2020-03-27T23:11:42.209Z",
  "requestId": "69f5c441-409h-493s-8da5-2361c5055fd8",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": true
}
```

I am unable to understand what AWS service is throwing this exception.
Is this exception thrown by my lambda or some other AWS service ?

Also what can be done to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

As per **AWS**, it says:

> Throttling is intended to **protect your resources** and downstream applications. Though [Lambda automatically scales](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html) to accommodate your incoming traffic, your function can still be throttled **for various reasons**.

Technically it could be a programming error or it's possible that throttles that you're seeing aren't on your Lambda function. Throttles can also occur on **API calls** during your function's invocation. I will put some points from AWS documentation on **how to identify** what is causing the throttling:

1. Verify if you see throttling messages in Amazon CloudWatch Logs but no corresponding data points in the Lambda Throttles metrics. If there are no Lambda Throttles metrics, the throttling is happening on API calls in your Lambda function code.
2. Check your function code for any throttled API calls. If certain API calls are throttled, be sure to use [exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) in your code to retry the API calls.
3. If you determine that you need a higher transactions per second (TPS) quota for an API call, you can [request a service quota increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/request-quota-increase.html), if the quota is adjustable.

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-troubleshoot-throttling/)

Comment: Ever seen a huge number LambdaThrottling errors in a low traffic web site, hosted as an Express app in a Lambda function, sitting behind a single Load Balancer instance?  It can't be a concurrency limit issue, the site gets at most 3 visitors a day.  And it has the same pattern.  First browser request, almost all 502/LambdThrottling errors.  Browser retries immediately & most requests are fulfilled except 2 or 3 fail permanently with ERR_ABORTED.  No errors showing in the Lambda monitor graphs or Cloudwatch logs, at all.  But tons of errors in the Load Balancer access logs.

Comment: @RobertOschler I haven't experienced this myself but 3 visitors per day is very low traffic and probably Lambda is doing a Cold Start every time which is causing timeouts depending on how much stuff your lambda is loading at the time of start.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by simply pausing the function execution for a few milliseconds after each AWS API call. Here's an example (notice `await sleep(..)` calls:

```
for (; ;) {
  const describeLogStreamsResponse = await cloudWatchLogs.describeLogStreams(describeLogStreamsRequest).promise();
  await sleep(700);
  for (let i = 0; i < describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams.length; i++) {
    const logStream = describeLogStreamsResponse.logStreams[i];
   ...
      try {
        await cloudWatchLogs.deleteLogStream(deleteLogStreamRequest).promise();
        await sleep(1000);
      } 
       ....
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
};
```